# How do I create a button that consists of 2 different fonts? (In my case, Montserrat & Intro Script)

Tags: css, button, fonts

I'm trying to design a button that consists of 2 different fonts (and an icon). I've tried W3 Schools, but they don't cover that specific example.

The fonts in the button design are Montserrat and Intro Script.

Any advice or good resources? Thanks, in advance.

[Button Design Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqQny.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the text you want to make a different font in a span and then change the font for the span. You may need to play around with the vertical alignment to ge them to line up properly.

In the case below, I used `vertical-align: sub`

```css
button{
  background-color: #004d94;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

button i {
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

button > span{
  font-family: "Lobster Two";
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster+Two:ital@1&family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">


<button>
  <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
  Join the <span>crew</span> today
</button>
```

`

Comment: Hi Jamie. Sorry for the delayed response. Awesome! That's exactly what I need! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put multiple `span`s with different styles inside a single button.

```html
<button>
  <span style="font-family: 'Lobster';">
    Hello
  </span>
  <span style="font-family: 'Montserrat';">
    World!
  </span>
</button>
```